# MySQL function to replace comma separated values in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one column which has comma separated values(ids). I need to change corresponding values to them. I need MySQL function for replacing.

Here my table1.

```
id             name
-------------------
1              Lara

2              Smith

3              Antony

4              Ken
```

Here my table2

```
id            friends
---------------------

1             2,3

2             1,2

3             1,3

4             1,4,3,2
```

My MySQL function (get_names) should return names with comma separated instead of name'ids when I querying  my table2.

ex.

when I call like this

```
select get_names('1,2,3,4','Lara,Smith,Antony,Ken','3,1');
```

it should return `Antony,Lara`

Here

My

```
1st parameter is - total user ids with comma separated order

2nd parameter is - total user name with comma separated order (same order like user ids)

3rd parameter is - any no. of user ids with comma separated any order
```

Please help me.

Comment: 2 questions - 1. How many id-name pairs do you have in your actual data? 2. Can you do this replacement operation in application code instead?

Comment: @shree.pat18 Ans. 1. 100-500 data only  2. I couldnot able to do it in application.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend changing table 2, so that you wouldn't have comma separated values:

```
id            friends
---------------------

1             2
1             3

2             1
2             2

3             1
3             3

4             1
4             4
4             3
4             2
```

In this case, you would have to change your MySQL function too, but it will be easier to retrieve values with a simple join.

Comment: hi. I will increase the row count in table and also when I showing this table in single row it will be very difficult

Comment: @SathishBabu Absolute nonsense

Comment: @Strawberry are u suggesting me to use above concept ?

Comment: Yes. See normalization - although the `id` column in the example above is a little unusual. It's more common to simply store friend pairs.

Answer (score 0):

comma separated values in mysql is the Violation of 1st NF